# How to calculate cumulative percent change by each group?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'd like to create a new column to calculate the cumulative percent change by each group

Sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                     'Col_1':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
                     'Col_2':[55, 66, 77, 88, 99]})
```

Methodology: See example below

```
| Group |Col_1 | Col_2  |  Cumulative Percent Change            |
|-------|------|--------|---------------------------------------|
|    A  | 100  |  55    | 1                                     |
|    A  | 200  |  66    |(66-55)/55 + 1                         |
|    A  | 300  |  77    |((77-66)/66) + ((66-55)/55 + 1)        |
|    B  | 400  |  88    |  1                                    |
|    B  | 500  |  99    |((99-88)/88) + 1                       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `groupby` twice, once to compute the percent change (with `pct_change`) and once for the cumulative sum+1 (`cumsum` and `add(1)`):

```
df['CPC'] = (df.groupby('Group')['Col_2']
               .pct_change()
               .fillna(0)
               .groupby(df['Group'])
               .cumsum().add(1)
            )
```

output:

```
  Group  Col_1  Col_2       CPC
0     A    100     55  1.000000
1     A    200     66  1.200000
2     A    300     77  1.366667
3     B    400     88  1.000000
4     B    500     99  1.125000
```